# change margins of book class

Tags: margins, tufte

I'm typesetting a book using the tufte-book class. All pages have left-side margin but in some pages I have to set the margin on the right side! 
Any ideas on how to get this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is not very clear. Each page has left and right margin :-). Do you have two sided document (what is expected for books)? Can you show your problem with small, complete document, which will show your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention. As you may know, in tufte-book class we have two column in each page, The wider for text and the narrower for side notes and etc.

Comment: I see something in ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf (page 29 or 30)

Comment: Are you looking for the `symmetric` documentclass option, by chance?

Comment: My project is a twoside book in which the margin (I mean the narrower column) is on the right side in even pages and on the left side in odd pages. However, in some parts of the book I have to set the margin on the left side for both even and odd pages. I am looking for the solution.